# ActionScript 3 Opposite of the "is" Reserved Keyword

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, casting, reserved-words

Just to slake my curiosity, what is the opposite of the `is` reserved keyword in ActionScript 3, as shown in this example:

```
if (myObject is ArrayCollection) {
  //Do stuff...
} else {
  //Do something else...
}
```

So that I could do something like this:

```
if (myObject isnotoperator ArrayCollection) {
  //Do something else...
} else {
  //Do stuff...
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there is one.  Instead I prefix the statement with the boolean not operator like so:

```
if (!(myObject is ArrayCollection)) {
  //Do stuff...
} else {
  //Do something else...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know wrapping a whole statement like that isn't considered good practice, but at least know I know an `is not` operator doesn't exist.

Comment: Also take a look at the "as" keyword, as that could be useful to you